# Driving the robot up a ramp

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I wont to do some test with my platform. My platform is an electrical wheelchair and I wont to calculate some parameters during the driving. I wont to drive it up and down a ramp and I wont to know how to calculate when the platform is up or down the ramp. So I will start in some point (horizontal level) and drive up the rmp till the end. So how to calculate that??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62738/driving-the-robot-up-a-ramp/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-14**:
Very interesting !

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-14**:
So any help????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you have an IMU, look at the pitch angle:

1. should be below a flat surface threshold, e.g. 5°
2. wait until above threshold for ramp angle, e.g. 20° -> on ramp
3. wait until below flat surface threshold, e.g. 5° -> off ramp

It's basically like a Schmitt-Trigger if you are familiar with that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-15**:
yeas, but IMU is very drifted, Only based on  IMU will not give such accurate results

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-15**:
is it possible to use the pose from Hactor mapping or amcl that has a pitch component?

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-15**:
I have a map of the environment so want to use the pose for that purspose

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-05-15**:
You have a very crappy IMU than I think. A simple accelerometer should be able to correctly measure the angle of the gravity vector.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-05-15**:
The pitch angle of an IMU should not have drift.